# Localhost in Safari loads old html

Tags: google-chrome, caching, safari, localhost

I've run into a very strange problem. Localhost in Safari is not updating any changes I make in my code. When I inspect elements I have altered, the old html is still shown. Chrome displays all changes.

I have cleared all cache, cleared the browser history, restarted the server and rebooted the browser. I updated macOS to Ventura which initially triggered the same inexplicable problem in Chrome as well, but it eventually disappeared (and I'm none the wiser...). Safari still has the same issue. When I opened localhost in a private window, it loaded newer html and I thought I had finally solved the issue, but it seems to have been a one-time occurrence - on refreshing the page, it still shows the same html (although it has been changed and saved in VS code), and opening localhost in another private window also shows the same html.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I guess it *must* have something to do with cache, but as mentioned, I've already tried clearing EVERYTHING multiple times and the problem still remains unsolved.

It's a WordPress project, using Bedrock, Timber, Tailwind and Parcel.

I'm super thankful for any and all advise or suggestions you have!

Answer (score 0):

If you are reasonably familiar with HTTP status codes (not just 200 and 400), the easiest thing to do is read your web access log and see what the two browsers are sending. There might be differential or partially cached request.

Depending on your project and the stack that it is built on, this would be "expected" cause, and you might have to look at how you set content expiration.

If the logs don't fit with Safari's behavior (or you want to skip that), the best thing to do is enter classic tech-support mode:

Telnet to the port and manually make a request or two. Or use your favorite line command utility (`curl`, `wget`) but double check they don't do any caching... (I just don't use them often enough to tell you right here).

If it does turn out that Safari is caching and won't clear, I would double check by using a test user if you can keep the project running and log in as a secondary user (guest will force you to reboot clean in most Macs, so it would be peer non-guest account).

If you confirm it is just your Safari, and the buttons in the UI don't work, you will need to do some kind of manual cleanup of the Safari cache.

(I know this is *never* supposed to happen, but even in the modern world, I'm sure a caching subsystem wedges more than never).

(Long ago, I was the HTTP cache tester for Mozilla/Firefox, and also, used a lot of IE6 and early Safari... I've done this at least once in every browser I've used.)